# Object.keys, slice and splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, splice

**So I am still learning arrays and objects, and I'm a little bit stuck. 
   I made an example of array of objects:**

```
var something = {candy:[{name:"snickers", price:2},
                    {name:"bounty", price:3},
                    {name:"mars", price:4}]};

Object.keys(something.candy).filter(function(obj){
return console.log(something.candy[obj].name);
})
```

**1. Question - Why doesn't it work when I write.:**

```
var candy1 = Object.keys(something.candy);
candy1.filter(function(obj){
return console.log(obj.name);
});
```

**Isn't it practically the same code meaning as above?**

**2.Question How come slice works and splice doesn't???**

```
Object.keys(something.candy).filter(function(obj){
return console.log(something.candy[obj].name.slice(0,3));
})

Object.keys(something.candy).filter(function(obj){
return a(something.candy[obj].name.splice(1,3));
})
```

Comment: `something.candy` is already an array. Don't use `Object.keys` on it, just use filter directly: `something.candy.filter( function(obj) { obj.name; } )`.

Comment: `slice` work because there is a function `String.prototype.slice` and `splice` doesn't because there is no function `String.prototype.splice`. Because `name` is a string. Only arrays have `splice`.

Comment: I get it now thank you very much!!!! @ibrahimmahrir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's helpful to pull each piece apart and look at it when learning this. For example you have an object:

```js
var something = {candy:[{name:"snickers", price:2},
                {name:"bounty", price:3},
                {name:"mars", price:4}]};

// what is something.candy:

console.log("candy:", something.candy)

// an array -- so what do you get with Object.keys?

var candy1 = Object.keys(something.candy)
console.log("keys:", candy1)

// just the indexes!

// So when you try to filter
candy1.filter(function(obj){
    // there is no obj.name becuase each object is just a number
    return console.log(obj);
});
```

I think you want to just do this:

```js
var something = {candy:[{name:"snickers", price:2},
                    {name:"bounty", price:3},
                    {name:"mars", price:4}]};

var select = something.candy.filter(obj => {
  console.log(obj.name) // look at them all
  return obj.name === "mars" // just pick this one
})

console.log("filtered: ", select)
```